# JMeter: Simulate real time concurrent users scenario with huge amount of data load and calculation on the fly

Tags: jmeter

I am totally new to JMeter, started working with this tool just from pass 4 days.

I have a webpage which queries Post grace DB and calculates some charts and metrics on the fly. I have designed a Test Plan to simulate this scenario for 10 concurrent users as below:

[image: JMeter Test Plan design]

I have used various Response assertions to mark the sample as pass after the page is loaded:
[image: Response assertion]
[image: Response assertion to verify if Reach analysis dashboard is loaded]

Below is the Summary report for the above test Plan with 10 concurrent users:
[image: Summary Report]

In above report, the result shows the avg time for the request as few milliseconds. But that is not true. After a particular dashboard page has loaded, data continues to load and it takes quite some time to load as calculations are done on the fly. As soon as response is received and UI is loaded, JMeter marks that sample request as pass.

I want to simulate concurrent scenario with the complete load of data. I want the tool to wait till complete data is loaded on the dashboard page and then mark the request as pass and show the total time taken to load the Dashboard page along with the data. My intention is to find how the server response time degrades with 10 concurrent users accessing different dashboards with huge data loads.

I require help to simulate such a real time scenario and if this is possible with JMeter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First of all make sure to add [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) to your Test Plan and configure it to download all embedded resources:

   [image: JMeter Embedded Resources]
2. If data loading is being made via [AJAX requests](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) JMeter won't execute them automatically, as per [JMeter project main page](http://jmeter.apache.org/):

   > JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, **JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages**. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does

   So you will need to "help" JMeter to kick off the requests by either building [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers manually or recording them via [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder). Just be aware that real browsers execute AJAX requests in parallel so you will need to put these requests under [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter)

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer. I will go through the parallel Controller article

Comment: U suggested to use Parallel Controller but there is a option next to "Retrieve All Embedded Resources" called "Parallel Downloads". From name it seems that when enabled, this option can also do the job of doing multiple requests in parallel. Is my understanding correct or am i missing something?

Answer (score 2):

IF you are looking at calculating Page Load time, render time, DOM downloadtime time, then there are many tools available which can help you. Though Jmeter will be able to give you DNS, connect time, First Byte time, Latency. However for Page Analysis you can refer to free tool such WebPageTest or even developer toolbar can help you. 
for Developer toolbar You can go to performance tab and then try to get the metrics, also please try to find out whether you are working on Single Page Application or Multipage Application.